# Detect Flash Content on website

Tags: php, flash, function

I'm trying to create a function that checks if users have flash on there website. 
So far I have this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.test.com'); //users website
if(preg_match(".swf", $html, $matches)) {
    print("<pre>"); 
    print_r($matches); 
    print("</pre>");
}
```

But I don't get any results.
Anyone got ideas? :)

Comment: This looks ok, assuming that the particular index web page has any text '.swf'.

Comment: @Wtower No, tp be precise: it looks if it contains some string consisting of 4 characters: an arbitrary one followed by the letters 'swf'. But anyway: such "detection" is extremely unreliable.

Comment: For example: www.disneylandparis.nl has flash (and a .swf) The function should work with this url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.disneylandparis.nl/'); //users website
$subject = $html;
$pattern = '/.swf/S';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Ruub, as Shankar Damodaran has suggested adjusting the regex works.

Comment: Marked yours as the accepted answer, because searching for .swf more reliable :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of searching for `.swf` , you could search for this text `flashplayer` , since most flash developers add this line of text since if the client browser has no flash installed , they use this URL to redirect the browser. So you can rely on this as of current scenario.

This URL will be there on most of the flash websites..

```
<a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?promoid=JZEFT" id="Download_AdobeFlashPlayer">Don't have Flash ? Get Adobe Flash Player Here</a>
```

**`EDIT :`**

Go with `strpos` instead.

```
<?php
$htmlsrc=file_get_contents('http://www.disneylandparis.nl');
if(strpos($htmlsrc,'flashplayer')!==false)
{
    echo "This website uses flash !";
}
```

Comment: I tried you answer. That would result in this:
`$html = file_get_contents('http://www.disneylandparis.nl'); 
if(preg_match("get.adobe.com", $html, $matches)) { 
 print("<pre>"); 
 print_r($matches); 
 print("</pre>");
}`
Stil, no results..

Comment: Because yeah they have a new URL `<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' border='0' /></a>
</center></div>`  So I think the best keyword will be **flashplayer**

Comment: Well, it seems that whatever I try, I always get zero results. Even if you search for 'disney', it doesn't find anything..

Comment: @Ruub, Check the edited answer. Seems like your regex is failing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked indeed. I marked @MrIllwind as the accepted answer, because searching for .swf more reliable :)